# All my directories are accessible magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, .htaccess

All my directories (except app/) and my root files (install.php, index.php,.gitignore...) are accessible to the users..
Is it a problem ?
I need to create a .htaccess for each my directories ?

Thanks !

PS: i don't know why but i can't say hello (when i'm editing this message)

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess in each folder

Take a look at the following

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/.htaccess

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/dev/.htaccess

And so on

Comment: But if I put .htaccess in media folder (for example), all my images won't displays on my website, isn't it ?

Comment: There are exceptions.  For example take a look at this https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/media/.htaccess